# How to determine number of IOPS used by a query in SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, performance, metrics

This question has arisen because a query we are running intermittently times out. The question is not about sorting out the problem query itself, but how to generally interpret the information available.

I've seen that when these timeouts occur, our "Data IO Percentage" via the Azure Portal and *sys.dm_db_resource_stats* is hitting 100%.

Using the *sys.dm_user_db_resource_governance* stored procedure, I see that my *primary_group_max_i*o is 160, therefore my IOPS (input / output per second) limit is 160. So far so good.

Coming from the query side, I'm using a query (shown in full below) that uses the *sys.query_store_runtime_stats* table to get IO read information (the query only does a select). I can see from this that for the query having problems the *avg_physical_io_reads* value is 5000, which is bigger than other queries going on (being 0 - 500).

A third angle I used was the "Live Query Statistics" in SQL Server Management Studio, which has an "actual number of rows read" for different nodes of the query plan.

The questions are:

- How are the *avg_physical_io_reads* and IOPS related? Can they be related?
- How do I know if 5000 *avg_physical_io_reads* is big in relation to my 160 IOPS limit from Azure? It looks like it, but the queries with *avg_physical_io_reads* of 500 are ok.
- Are the "Live Query Statistics" rows read in any way relatable to the logical and physical io reads of the *query_store_runtime_stats*?
- Are there any other diagnostics that can tell me how much a particular query will impact my Azure IOPS limits?

Full query for sys.query_store_runtime_stats that I've been using:

```
SELECT
qsrsi.start_time,
qsrsi.end_time,
qsq.query_id,
qsq.query_text_id,
qsp.plan_id,
qsq.last_execution_time,
count_executions,
qsq.count_compiles,
avg_duration/1000 as [Avg_Duration(ms)],
min_duration/1000 as [Min_Duration(ms)],
max_duration/1000 as [Max_Duration(ms)],
avg_logical_io_reads,
min_logical_io_reads,
max_logical_io_reads,
avg_physical_io_reads,,
min_physical_io_reads,
max_physical_io_reads,
avg_rowcount,
min_rowcount,
max_rowcount,
avg_num_physical_io_reads,
min_num_physical_io_reads,
max_num_physical_io_reads,
qsqt.query_sql_text,
query_plan,
qsq.query_hash
from sys.query_store_query qsq
INNER JOIN sys.query_store_query_text qsqt ON qsq.query_text_id = qsqt.query_text_id
INNER JOIN sys.query_context_settings qcs ON qsq.context_settings_id = qcs.context_settings_id
INNER JOIN sys.query_store_plan qsp ON qsq.query_id = qsp.query_id
INNER JOIN sys.query_store_runtime_stats qsrs ON qsrs.plan_id = qsp.plan_id
INNER JOIN sys.query_store_runtime_stats_interval qsrsi ON qsrs.runtime_stats_interval_id = qsrsi.runtime_stats_interval_id
WHERE qsrsi.start_time >= @starttime and qsrsi.start_time <= @endtime
ORDER BY qsrsi.start_time
```

Comment: What resource limit do we have configured on Azure SQL?
According to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/resource-limits-vcore-single-databases, The vCore configuration only has the maximum data IOPs information. Utilization depends on the resource limit.

Comment: Hey John, did you get answer to this question

Answer (score -1):

The configuration only has the maximum data IOPs information. Utilization depends on the resource limit. refer  [docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/…](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/resource-limits-vcore-single-databases),
[image]

2. The vCore configuration only has the maximum data IOPs information. Utilization depends on the resource limit. we can get IOPS information using this query

   ```
   SELECT * FROM sys.dm_user_db_resource_governance
   ```
3. To verify the sleeping connection instances on Sql Server Database

```
    SELECT  DB_NAME(dbid) as DBName,  Count(dbid) as NumberOfConnetions,  Status  FROM  sys.sysprocesses with (nolock)  WHERE  dbid>0  GROUP BY  dbid, loginname,status;
```

4. We can verify the query logs / long running queries form Azure portal itself under  **Intelligence Performance window**
   [image]

Comment: I don't believe this answers the question. I know my resource limits, as stated in the question (we are using DTU based pricing, not vCore). I have also used the "query performance insights". True, it does give a "Data IO %" for a query (though this seems in no way to account for the DTU usage). However, how could a "data IO %" be understood from the sys.query_store_runtime_stats query?

Comment: Timeouts was caused because of DTU based configuration - indirectly points to "Max concurrent sessions".  "How many sessions we have per minute. If session count exceeds, we will get time out errors until those sleeping connections will clear.  The query on step3 helps to find the sleeping thread information.
IOPS is indirectly on the tags to price tier. Example if it basic / Standard tier : 1-4 IOPS per DTU and it if premium it will be >25 IOPS per DTU.  "sys.query_store_runtime_stats" - Represents runtime statistics to get actual state for every interval you need to aggregate metrics

Comment: Hope I answered your question: please refer this link for more information on "sys-query-store-runtime-stats" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-query-store-runtime-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Sorry to take time to respond. I have run the sys.sysprocesses query against my database.  I have the following output: 1 runnable, 2 background & 17 sleeping. Is that problematic numbers or not? It seems a similar profile to other databases I have.

Comment: this does not answer question